# Is it possible to use CockroachDB with the Java Transaction API (JTA)?

Tags: java, jpa, jta, google-cloud-spanner, cockroachdb

I've seen the project via developpez.com

https://www.developpez.com/actu/118014/Cloud-Spanner-Google-lance-pour-le-grand-public-sa-solution-de-bases-de-donnees-globales-offrant-un-bon-compromis-entre-SQL-et-NoSQL/

CockroachDB seems to supports ACID transactions. So my question is:
Is it possible to use it with JPA and JTA?

Comment: Your link seems to be about Google Cloud Spanner, not CockroachDB. Regarding your question: How about you try it?

Comment: At the end of article, they are speaking about cockroachDB. Yes i can try it.  
I see that it can be used with hibernate, but no details about jpa and jta.

Answer (score 3):

CockroachDB is compatible with the JDBC API, via the Postgres `pgjdbc` driver. Since JPA and JTA connect to databases via JDBC, they should be useable against CockroachDB as long as you use the `pgjdbc` driver.

If you're using Maven, you can add the following declaration to your `pom.xml` to add a dependency on `pgjdbc`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace `VERSION` with a driver version selected from the [list in Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22).